# What advice is there for aspiring journalists and authors?

Tags: style

As an aspiring writer/blogger, I'm finding it hard to know where to start. I'd like to be able to get some work of mine, possibly from [my blog](http://pyme.thecodelobby.com/), in a local newspaper.

1. What advice is there for aspiring and young writers trying to get pieces of work in a local newspaper?
2. How should I go about contacting the right people for this, such as editorials? What manner should I have towards them?
3. Is my current writing style appropriate for a newspaper column or highlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask.

Provided that you're reasonably polite and that you don't act like you're *entitled* to have your work featured in the paper, you're unlikely to make any enemies simply by asking. Most newspapers have email or postal addresses listed somewhere; sending them an email or a letter can't hurt.

Phrases like "Are you looking for new content for [newspaper]?" or "Would you be interested in..." spring to mind. I'd also recommend picking one or two of your best pieces of writing, having them proofread by a friend - or anybody whose English you trust, really - and sending them in. Don't count on them researching you by going and reading your blog.

As far as style goes, there exist newspapers for every writing style on Earth; it depends on the paper. For a typical newspaper *column*, I'd say your writing style is okay, if maybe a little informal. They may disagree, though; it's hard to tell without knowing the newspaper or the editor.

Content, though, may be a problem. This may be a different story for your local newspaper, but I'd imagine the demographic that reads print newspapers and that which has a keen interest in programming don't overlap much. It's not an absolute "it'll never happen", but I think it's something you should give some consideration.

Comment: I wasn't planning on writing programming things for the newspaper, by the way, but thanks for your answer!

Comment: Just working off the content of your blog, as far as my skimming took me. No problem at all.